# Is potentitally interesting a combination of the Landau's problem related to primes of the form $n^2+1$ and the Rassias' conjecture?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, conjectures

This morning I wondered about next question. I am going to ask it as a soft question and as a reference request. My main goal is to know if it is interesting.

One of the Landau's problems is to state if there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+1$. See it from this [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_problems) On the other hand I know other open problem, the so-called Rassias' conjecture, see this [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rassias%27_conjecture)

A well known important heuristic is the so-called abc conjecture. I am saying the version *ABC Conjecture II* from the Wikipedia's article dedicated to the abc conjecture.

> **Question.** Could be potentially interesting a combination betweeen the statement of the mentioned Landau's problem (the form of such primes $n^2+1$) and Rassias' conjecture? If it was in the literature refer it, and I try to find and read those statements and calculations, in other case provide us your reasonings or heuristic to know if such combination that I've evoked is interesting in the context of primes conjectures. **Many thanks.**

Comment: Rassias' conjecture is basically about two linear polynomials $x$ and $(p-1)x-1$ simultaneously taking a prime value, making it a special case of [Dickson's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_conjecture), as one of the linked articles notes. This is greatly generalized by [Schinzel's hypothesis H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H).

Comment: Many thanks @Wojowu I am going to see the Wikipedia's article. Feel free to expand or edit your comment as an answer.

Comment: Everyone the comparison that I did (I don't know if my way is potentially interesting) was: I suppose that Rassias' conjecture holds and that $1+n^2$ is prime, then the abc conjecture implies that $\forall\epsilon>0$ there exists a positive (constant) $C(\epsilon)$ such that $n^2<C(\epsilon)p_1^{\epsilon}p_2^{1+\epsilon}\operatorname{rad}(n)^{1+\epsilon}$, where $\operatorname{rad}(m)$ is the radical of an integer, see this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) and I've used the version [ABC Conjecture II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture#Formulations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know which exactly connection do you want to see. A completely elementary and short approach would be:

Suppose that $p=n^2+1$ is prime. Then, if Rassias´ conjecture is true we have:

$p=n^2+1= \dfrac {p_1+p_2+1}{p_1}$. for some primes $p_1<p_2$

That is, we have $n^2p_1-p_2=1$.

Because $\gcd (n^2,-1)=1$ [Bezout´s identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) guarantees that we have an infinite number of solutions $(x,y)$ to the equation $n^2x-y=1$ but here, we need both of them to be positive different primes.

Comment: I did not see this answer until today, many thanks. I think I have enough feedback with your answer, and the first comment about  Dickson's conjecture and Schinzel's hypothesis H.